# How could I track if user decide to sign up or they exit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I have a page `/see_more_details`

if user has signed and logged , they can view the details data,

Otherwise I will show a pop up, and show an login hint

If they click the button `/users/auth/facebook/` and logged , that means I reach my target.

If the leave away, it means I lose one client.

How could I track the behaviour with `Rails` and `Google GA`

Currently, I just show the `GA` tracking code for every page.

```
- if Rails.env == "production"
  :javascript
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', "UA-XXXX43-1"]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
```

But I don't know how to get the information I want, thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should push a track event on `see_more_details` page to mark user trying to view when if user unsigned, like:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'see_more_details', 'try'])
```

Then if user signed in, push two event:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'see_more_details', 'try'])
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'see_more_details', 'signed'])
```

So, in `GA`, numbers of `try` event shows how many times the page has been viewed, and numbers of `signed` can tell how many clients actually signed and viewed detail, And the difference between is how many close.